# Context API - state is cleared on route change

Tags: reactjs

Okay so I'm using context API to handle state for my application. I have a sign in page, and a main page. Once I sign in, all my state gets successfully saved to my global state - in a Provider Class. The sign in works fine because I have a header that displays whether the user is signed in or not.

I'm trying to set up some error handling to prevent somebody from manually accessing the sign in page once they're signed in.

The problem is, all my state gets erased from my global Provider Class once I manually type in /signin. Sorry I have no code, I'm assuming there is something I missing here when it comes to using context api to manage state. Is there is a reason why my Provider class is doing this? and how to stop it from happening?

Comment: By 'manually type in /signin', do you mean in your browser's address bar?

Comment: Are you using `HashRouter`? I'm afraid you're going to have to provide us with some code samples if we're to be much help.

Comment: If you are doing what @Dylan Walker said, you are essentially refreshing your app which will clear any stored data in your Provider state. The same thing happens in redux. You should look at storing that information in local storage or cookies. That way you can still refer to it after a refresh.

Comment: Yes, by manually I do mean typing in the address bar. I was unaware the app refreshes when you type in the address bar - this all makes sense now. I will look at storing the information in cookies